# Knockout.JS : self.myObservable is not a function, issues with code order

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have page using knockout, which has a searchfield, selectedvalue from a dropdown, and pagenumber..

All these are *initialized* at set to defaultvalues, especially for first run / page access..

The problem is that i dont understand why i'm getting the following error

```
"self.selectedTeamId is not a function()"
```

I know.. this has to be something with the "order of things", so that when it's being used, it has **NOT** been initialized yet.

Can someone correct my mistake ?

**CODE :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.photos = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedTeamId = ko.observable(0);
    self.searchString = ko.observable('');
    self.pageNumber = ko.observable(1);

    self.clearFilters = function() {
        self.searchString('');  // set default to ''
        self.selectedTeamId(0); // set default to 0
        self.pageNumber(1);  // set default to 1
        self.getPhotos();
    };

    self.getPhotos = function () {
        var photoParams = "?teamId=" + self.selectedTeamId() + "&search=" + encodeURIComponent(self.searchString()) + "&pageNumber=" + self.pageNumber();
        $.get("api/Photo/GetPhotos" + photoParams,
            function(data) {
                self.photos(data);
            }, "json");
    };
};
var photosModel = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(photosModel, document.getElementById("photoarchive"));

// THE NEXT LINE GIVES THE ERROR (self.selectedTeamId())
var photoParams = "?teamId=" + self.selectedTeamId() + "&search=" + encodeURIComponent(self.searchString()) + "&pageNumber=" + self.pageNumber();
$.get("api/Photo/GetPhotos" + photoParams,
    function(data) {
        photosModel.photos(data);
    }, "json");
});
```

Comment: When you say "THE NEXT LINE GIVES THE ERROR" - is that an _actual_ duplicated line of code, or are you just repeating the contents of `self.getPhotos` within your question?

Comment: No.. this is the complete code.. It could probably be written a lot better (not duplicating the api call .. As you see.. one api call is executed when loading the page, and one api call getPhotos() is called when a button is clicked (for filtering, searching etc..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is a variable which is local to your `ViewModel` function. It isn't accessible outside of that function.

As you're storing your `ViewModel` within your `photosModel` variable, you can instead access the `selectedTeamId` observable with:

```
photosModel.selectedTeamId()
```

You'll need to do the same with `self.searchString()` and `self.pageNumber()`.

That said, however, you may as well just call `photosModel.getPhotos()` instead of duplicating the entire function outside of the `ViewModel` scope.

Comment: If this is indeed what's going on, OP could remove all that duplicated code and just call `photosModel.getPhotos()`

Comment: Doing the noted changes right now.. will post back here in a few minutes  : ) Thanks by the way !

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you for extremely quick and direct answer.. This solved my problem imminently ! :)